# Why does KeyEventArgs have virtual properties?

Tags: .net

I noticed in the documentation of the [`KeyEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class that it has some odd modifiers on its properties: some are virtual, others are not:

- `virtual`: `Alt`, `Shift`
- normal: `Control`, `Modifiers`

Why are `Alt` and `Shift` virtual, whereas the rest are not? I can not think of a good reason for this, certainly because, as far as I can tell, the `KeyEventArgs` class is not derived from.

Comment: The typical answer for something like this is... because that's the way it was written.  Something like this goes back to the very first versions of .net.  It's unlikely anyone really knows

Comment: This is untraceable.  It *might* have made some sense if all the modifier key properties were virtual, perhaps relevant in one of the many Windows Mobile versions or related to an old IME.  Bigger problem is that Control is not virtual.  It doesn't read like anything more but a simple mistake.  It of course does not matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess (at least for the *Alt* key):

Maybe because of the existence of *[AltGr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)* - it's an implementation decision for the current culture info / key-mapping / keyboard driver.

**Update**: As explicitly stated above, it's a guess. According to @HansPassant (see comment below), *AltGr* is a dead key. I won't argue about the subject, just thought it may have a connection to the same old *Alt* key.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Do you mean that they want to keep the option open to add a new version of KeyEventArgs by deriving from the current one, and then returning a different value for `Alt` to allow `Ctrl+Alt -> AltGr` to either work or explicitly not work?

Comment: AltGr is a dead key, used to enter diacritics.  Doesn't have anything to do with the Alt key.